# Pascal-style arrays, built-in len() function vs .length? What are the pros/cons

Tags: language-design

What are the differences between these two? Why would you pick one over the other, is it just personal preference, or is there an actual reason behind why you would use either a built-in function or whatever `.length` is.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `*.length` over `*.length()` or `len(*)` is kind of a historical artifact, which was probably done to make getting the `length` of an array as fast as possible. Arrays after all, are a very basic data structure in many languages, and getting the length of one is an extremely common operation. And accessing a property is much faster than calling a method.

Nowadays a compiler could probably optimize that kind of thing out, but back then I think there was a pull towards ease-of-implementation which guided many languages to simply have `*.length` as a property.

However, in any OOP language at least, it's more consistent to have `*.length()`, because while arrays have immutable lengths, and can afford to have `*.length` exposed as a constant value, other data structures which you can add or remove values would not be able to do this.